# Cats EitherT.collectRight can't find Alternative[Future]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'm trying to find an example for Cats `EitherT.collectRight`. I've a `EitherT[Future, String, Event]` and when I do `collectRight,` I get

```
Error:(79, 18) could not find implicit value for parameter FA: cats.Alternative[scala.concurrent.Future]
            elem.collectRight
```

I've an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope, so [this](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/faq.md#future-instances) FAQ doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

There is no instance for `Alternative[Future]`, nor should there be. Here's the type definition:

```
trait Alternative[F[_]] extends Applicative[F] with MonoidK[F]
```

`Applicative[Future]` is fine. But `MonoidK[F]` doesn't make sense for `Future`. From the comment on `MonoidK`:

> - `Monoid[A]` allows `A` values to be combined, and also means there
>     is an "empty" `A` value that functions as an identity.
> - `MonoidK[F]` allows two `F[A]` values to be combined, for any `A`.  It
>     also means that for any `A`, there is an "empty" `F[A]` value. The
>     combination operation and empty value just depend on the
>     structure of `F`, but not on the structure of `A`.

How would you construct an "empty" `Future[A]` for any `A`? How would you combine two `Future[A]`s into one? You can see how this would be possible with `List`, but to me it's nonsensical for `Future`. Perhaps you have some behavior you're expecting and you could implement `Applicative[Future]` yourself. But I suspect the real issue is you want something other than `collectRight`.

For example, what do you expect to happen with this?

```
val e: EitherT[Future, String, Event] = Future(Left("hello"))
val result: Future[Event] = e.collectRight // should return what?... failure?
```

Comment: I'd expect a failed future for your example, something like `Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("whatever"))`. What I'm after is to transform the `EitherT` into another shape, but that seems to be surprisingly difficult. I can do it with one of the `fold`, but was hoping for a simpler option.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to a Abhijit Sarkar's comment to JoeK's answer that is too big for a comment.

First of all I agree with Joe that you attempt to use `collectRight` is quite suspicious. It looks like what you really need is `getOrElse` or `getOrElseF`. For example this seems to match the behavior described in your comment

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class Event(val a: Int)

val eGood: EitherT[Future, String, Event] = EitherT[Future, String, Event](Future(Right(Event(42))))
val resultGood: Future[Event] = eGood.getOrElseF(Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("whatever")))
val eBad: EitherT[Future, String, Event] = EitherT[Future, String, Event](Future(Left("hello")))
val resultBad: Future[Event] = eBad.getOrElseF(Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("whatever")))

println("good = " + scala.concurrent.Await.result(resultGood, 1 second))
println()
scala.concurrent.Await.result(resultBad, 1 second)) // don't need println as there will be exception anyway
```

prints

> good = Event(42)
>   
>   
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: whatever
>   
>   at sg.cats.CatsMain$.$anonfun$resultBad$1(CatsMain.scala:32))
>   
>  at ...

Note that `Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("whatever"))` is effectively what `Alternative[Future]` should have had as its `empty` implementation. And this is one of the places where there is no solution that fits all scenarios. Still, if you are too bored to type that all the time and you have the same failure that matches all your cases, you can create your implicit operation such as:

```
final class MyEitherFutureOps[A, B](val eab: EitherT[Future, A, B]) extends AnyVal {

  import cats.instances.future._

  def rightOrFailure(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[B] = eab.getOrElseF(Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("whatever")))
}

object MyEitherFutureOps {
  implicit def ops[A, B](eab: EitherT[Future, A, B]): MyEitherFutureOps[A, B] = new MyEitherFutureOps[A, B](eab)

}
```

and then you may use it as

```
import MyEitherFutureOps._

val eGood: EitherT[Future, String, Event] = EitherT[Future, String, Event](Future(Right(Event(42))))
val resultGood: Future[Event] = eGood.rightOrFailure
val eBad: EitherT[Future, String, Event] = EitherT[Future, String, Event](Future(Left("hello")))
val resultBad: Future[Event] = eBad.rightOrFailure
```

with the same effect as in the example above.

Comment: `resultGood` is the same as `resultBad`, both failed?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, no `resultGood` is a `Future` that contains `Event(42)`. This is the behavior you wanted, isn't it? I've updated code sample to clarify output.

Answer (score 1):

post is almost 2yrs old now, but how about simple:

```
val e: EitherT[Future, String, Event] = ???
val result: Future[Event] = e.value.flatMap {
  case Right(event) => Future.successful(event)
  case Left(e)      => Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("whatever with: " + e))
  //case Left(e) => Future.successful(???) //some recover from String to Event
}
```

or am I missing something?